# Using LAST_INSERT_ID() to insert newest id from one table to another

Tags: php, mysql

I know there are many questions about this topic. I read almost all of them, but I keep getting MySQL syntax errors. I'm using my `WAMP` server atm. I checked my `MySQL` version to be 5.7.9, so this should be ok.

I have this query:

```
INSERT INTO users (profile_pic, first_name, last_name, 
address, zip, city, phone, age, job, education, registration_date, email, pass) 
VALUES ('$final_profile_pic_file', '$first_name', '$last_name', '$address', '$zip', '$city', 
'$phone', '$age', '$job', '$education', NOW(), '$email', SHA1('$pass') ); 

INSERT INTO tickets (user_id, ticket_date) 
VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), NOW());
```

The first `INSERT` users works fine. I then want to put in the just created user id from the users table into the tickets table right away with `LAST_INSERT_ID()`. I also tried to put it as a variable and then use that variable as a value.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you are using `mysqli` then use the function for get the last id.And is the table setup right? `autoinc./primray key`

Comment: I have a column `user_id` which is `AI` and `primary key` in the users table. Can you make an example of what function you want to use @JOUM ? I am using `mysqli`

Comment: `$mysqli->insert_id` http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use `@mysqli_multi_query` instead of `@mysqli_query`. That solved the problem.

Comment: Using multi query and building your queries with string concatenation the way you are doing it is *almost an absolute guarantee* that you will be vulnerable to a SQL injection attack.  Either one is bad, together they are deadly.  Use. Prepared. Statements.